# How to do a pandas join if the match might appear in either of two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, list, datetime

Here is the situation: I have two pandas data frames:

TABLE 1:

| name | alias | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| str | str | str |

TABLE 2:

| name_or_alias | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| str | str | str |

table1.name and table1.alias all contain unique values. Meaning, there are no duplicates between either of the two columns.
I need to do a left join on table2, but the problem is that the column to join on may be either table1.name OR table1.alias.

So, if I do:

table2.merge(table2, how=left, on=name),

I will only get some of the matches. If I do:

table2.merge(table2, how=left, on=alias),

I will also only get some of the matches. What I tried to do is concat the two merges and remove the duplicates

`pd.concat([df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='name', right_on='name_or_alias'), df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='alias', right_on='name_or_alias')], axis=0).pipe(lambda x: x[x.index.duplicated()])`

but this doesn't remove the duplicates correctly because if the match was in one of the matches but not the other, then it wont be duplicated (since the rows will be null for one of the merges and not the other).

I need to figure out how to remove the rows if the match was found in the other table. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a less ambiguous example, not using `str` for all cells

Comment: the contents of the tables are not important though, theyre just random strings

Comment: It is important for clarity of the question

Answer (score 0):

You can `melt`, `merge`, and `drop_duplicates`:

```
(df1
 .reset_index()
 .melt(['index', 'col3'], value_name='name_or_alias')
 .merge(df2, on='name_or_alias', suffixes=(None, '_2'), how='left')
 .drop_duplicates('index')
 .set_index('index')
 )
```

*NB. To keep the original DataFrame, `join` the output to it.*

Output:

```
       col3 variable name_or_alias  col2  col3_2
index                                           
0         0     name             A   5.0     8.0
1         1     name             B   3.0     6.0
2         2     name             C   NaN     NaN
```

Used input:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'alias': ['D', 'E', 'F'], 'col3': [0, 1, 2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name_or_alias': ['B', 'D', 'A'], 'col2': [3, 4, 5], 'col3': [6, 7, 8]})
```

Comment: Thanks! It's giving me an index error though at the drop_duplicates part

Comment: Is your original index maybe duplicated? Please update the example to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that when you concat the 2 merged dataframes, it will generate duplicated records.

Assuming there are no duplicated values in `name_or_alias`, You can use [combine_first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) instead of `concat` to combine 2 merged dataframes

It will fill null values in first dataframe with non-null values from second dataframe

```
df3=df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='name', right_on='name_or_alias')
df4=df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='alias', right_on='name_or_alias')
df3.combine_first(df4)
```

example input:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Peter', 'Mary', 'John', 'Tom'],'alias': ['P', 'M', 'J', 'T'],'col3': ['a', 'b' , 'c', 'd']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name_or_alias': ['Peter', 'M', 'Tom'],'col2': ['e', 'f', 'g'],'col3': ['h', 'i' , 'j']})
```

output:

```
df1:
    name    alias   col3
0   Peter   P       a
1   Mary    M       b
2   John    J       c
3   Tom     T       d

df2:
    name_or_alias   col2    col3
0   Peter           e       h
1   M               f       i
2   Tom             g       j

result:
    name    alias   col3_x  name_or_alias   col2    col3_y
0   Peter   P       a       Peter           e       h
1   Mary    M       b       M               f       i
2   John    J       c       NaN             NaN     NaN
3   Tom     T       d       Tom             g       j
```

Comment: Thanks! Will the resulting data frame from line 3 have duplicates though, or would it take care of duplicate rows?

Comment: I tried this, and it gave me a resulting table bigger than the df2. The resulting table should have the same number of rows as df2. Any ideas?

Comment: @lia_strawberry As this is a left join with df1 as base, the resulting dataframe should have same number of records as df1 instead of df2, unless there are duplicated keys, e.g. duplicated name_or_alias. Please note combine_first will not work here if there are duplicated keys. I have also updated the answer with an example